# how to make a rectangle at run time to fit a dragged label of words in it objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, calayer

I am making a words match app in iOS in which i have two parts of words strings and I want to make a complete word from two labels of random words so for all is fine.

Now I want to make a rectangle at run time as a target of draggable label, when I click on label to drag it the rectangle should become hi-lighted with the same size as the size of label of words.

How can i achieve this in `objective-C`?

For more clearness you can see in image where I want to make this green rectangle at run time to drop the right side labels in it

The left side labels are not moveable and should always in the rectangle as you see in given image.The code so far i try to make the rectangle as a `UIView` in `viewDidLoad` as

```
for(int i = 0; i <5;i++){
customView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,y,50, 30)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[gameLayer addSubview:customView];
    y = y+40;
}
```

But this is not what i actually want. Any help appreciated...

Comment: UILabel not contain any action

Comment: user can drag UILabel with touches..

Comment: Talking about Pan Gesture.

Comment: no pane gestures applied

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: i mean i just make uilabel on a uiview and apply touches began method to drag it anywhere on the screen

Comment: do you understand my problem question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the rectangle size same as the size of tapped label as here, i make an array in .h file which contain the reference of my target rectangle `NSMutableArray *rectangleLabels`
after that i make the size of rectangle same as the size of my draggable labels using a loop in tapped gestures method and it works fine...

```
-(void)gotTapped:(Id)sender {
for (UIView *v in rectangleLabels) {
    v.hidden = !v.hidden;
    UILabel *tapLbl = (UILabel *)[sender view];
    CGRect rect = tapLbl.frame;
    for(int i=0;i<rectangleLabels.count;i++) {
        UILabel *lblChange = (UILabel *)[rectangleLabels objectAtIndex:i];
        lblChange.frame = CGRectMake(lblChange.frame.origin.x, lblChange.frame.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    }
}
```

}